# How to save XY coordinates in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a widget that looks like an equalizer, the scrubbing on the slider is working. When I relaunch the swf file everything resets.

What can I do to save the setting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/SharedObject.html). It allows you to save a limited amount of information on the client.

Comment: Yes. I think I left out some important information. The positioning of the slider bust be shown to all users that load the swf file.

Do you think XML would be able to do his...? I guess the problem with that is, the file would haft to be saved. 

Perhaps PHP? I dont know.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: How is the slider position set? Do clients have the ability to adjust it or do you set the value server side? Edit your question with more information about what you're doing and I might be able to help...

Comment: oh sure :)

What Im doing is setting up a bar graph using sliders and having the users set the heights of each one. So anyone else that opens the file will be able to see it. This will be shown locally.